# Запятая после "Конечно"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Выделяется ли запятой "конечно" в предложениях такого типа: "Конечно(,) нет!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно слово *конечно*, по материалам грамоты.ру, может и не быть вводным, а усилительным:

*Вы все это понимаете, конечно?* (*конечно* – вводное слово).

*Вы-то конечно приедете раньше меня* (*конечно*, произносимое тоном уверенности, – усилительное слово).

Если во 2-м примере считать *конечно* членом предложения, даже не знаю, какой вопрос надо поставить и от какого слова (*Приедете (как?) конечно* -- так, что ли?). Можно оправдать отсутствие запятой, разве что если *конечно=точно*:
*Вы-то конечно (точно, однозначно) приедете раньше меня.*

Тем не менее, считаю, что это плохая идея — ставить/не ставить знаки препинания в зависимость от интонации или от "тона уверенности/неуверенности" в рамках литературной нормы. Само *конечно* несет в себе уверенность. То есть оно может означать неуверенность, если выделить его запятыми (-ой), что ли? Лучше бы этот случай с невыделением слова *конечно* запятыми считался авторским случаем.

Здесь нужен другой критерий, по-моему: насколько информация объективна или же субъективна.

Если информация субъективна, то есть автор реплики считает, что нет, значит:
*Конечно, нет* — запятая бесспорно нужна.

Если предположить, что объективна, допустим, автор повествования заявляет:
*Конечно нет* — запятая по идее не нужна (это неоспоримая истина типа). Но все равно это мнение, и слово "конечно" хочется отделить от основного текста. Если же нужно подчеркнуть, что конечно=точно, так лучше не вносить неоднозначность и употребить более подходящее слово: *Точно нет*.

По-моему, такие правила делают из языка высшую математику и должны быть упрощены. Имхо...

Answer (score 4):

А я соглашусь с SoWa, что не так все просто с этим словом. Слово **конечно**, как и ряд других, может быть вводным словом - и тогда запятая (-ые) нужна (-ы), а может не быть вводным, тогда и запятая (-ые) на ставится. Оно не является вводным и НЕ выделяется запятыми, если произносится тоном уверенности, убежденности: Конечно же это так!
Поэтому в данном предложение наличие запятой будет зависеть от интонации.

Comment: Надо сказать, что чаще всего слово конечно запятыми выделяется. И если вдруг это задание из теста, запятую лучше поставить. В свободном письме наличие-отсутствие запятой передает интонацию предложения.

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите здесь: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_363. По-моему, вполне доходчиво.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: Конечно нет!

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

КОНЕЧНО

1) Частица. Употр. при выражении согласия, подтверждения сказанного; да, разумеется. Вы говорите по-английски? - Конечно!

2) Вводн. сл. Разумеется, несомненно. Конечно, привычка много значит. Вы, конечно, к нам придёте?

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

1) В качестве  усилительной частицы "конечно" может относиться к различным словам: конечно да, конечно нет, конечно правда, конечно получится, при этом ударение падает на частицу, что и придает выражению значение уверенности.

2) Однако значительно чаще "конечно" является вводным словом, относится ко всему предложению и обособляется.

АВТОРСКИЙ ВАРИАНТ

В некоторых случаях возможны варианты с авторским решением:

(1) Да, конечно, готовы. - (2) Да, конечно готовы. Варианты различаются интонацией: спокойная уверенность в первом случае и некоторая эмоциональность во втором. Реально это связано с акцентированием слова конечно в сочетании "конечно готовы", которое произносится без паузы.

ДРУГИЕ ПРИМЕРЫ

1) Обособляется

Да, конечно, берите, ― сказал Корнилов.

И я подумала: "Ну да, конечно, а кто же ещё?

2) Не обособляется

Да конечно получится, но это же нехорошо.

Ну да конечно же, как это он раньше не догадался, не понял!

Это один из лучших мультфильмов, да конечно большой вклад внесли именно мастера визуализации и звуковых эффектов с музыкой.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае - нет. Потому что это восклицание и тут выделять вообще ничего не надо.

А вот если дальше стоит какой-нибудь оборот, то выделять надо: "Конечно, мы могли бы реализовать такое, но..."

А вот тут опять же простое предложение: "Конечно мы это можем".

С третьей стороны - смотри на эмоциональную составляющую предложения и отсюда необходимость ставить запятую. Если "Конечно" будет иметь ярко-утвердительную окраску, то выделяй запятой.

Ох и каша получилась :)

Comment: Я думаю, Вы в последнем предложении хотели сказать "то НЕ выделяй запятой". А то действительно каша получается.

Comment: И в аватаре малаша

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что большинство вводных слов не выделяется в речи особой интонацией. Знаки выделения при вводных словах - это так называемые "нечитаемые" знаки. Поэтому нужно строго следовать принятым (и закреплённым в авторитетных изданиях) нормам правописания. 
Слово "конечно" является вводным. Оно не выделяется запятыми, только когда стоит в начале или в конце какого-то обособленного оборота.

Comment: Вполне с Вами согласна и слово "конечно"  выделяю запятой.  На сто процентов согласна с Вами, что ориентироваться надо на авторитетные источники. Поэтому  уже 25 лет покупаю только академические справочники. О том, что слово конечно, произносимое тоном уверенности, – усилительное слово, говорится и в Правилах 1956 года, и в справочнике Розенталя, и в "Правилах..." под редакцией Лопатина, и на портале "Грамота". Примеры приводят разной степени похожести на наш, но ни один источник не отрицает перехода слова конечно в усилительную частицу с отсутствием запятых.

Comment: Да и Вы сами говорите, что "большинство вводных слов не выделяется в речи особой интонацией". Значит, если все таки логическое ударение падает на это слово, если присутствует интонация убежденности и уверенности - это уже и не вводное .Зачем же запятые? Спасибо SoWa, что пришлось внимательно перечитать источники. Я почему-то тоже не замечала среди "наконец", "может быть" и т.п. слова конечно.

Comment: Поискала еще вузовские учебники. Там то же. Авторы - доктора наук. Например, Балашова, Дементьев. (Саратовский университет). Цитирую:"5) Слово конечно обычно выделяется запятыми в качестве вводного:
Федор ещё работал в тылу, слыхал, конечно, и читал многократно о «народных героях» (Фурманов).
Но иногда слово конечно, произносимое тоном уверенности, убеждённости, приобретает значение утвердительной частицы и пунктуационно не выделяется:
Конечно правда!; Конечно же это так."

Answer (score 0):

Не соглашусь с [[@SoWa](/users/1013/sowa)](/users/1013/sowa). У слова *"конечно"* всего два значения:

1. *вводное слово,* само собой разумеется, без сомнения;
2. *в знач. утвердительной частицы,* да, разумеется.

---

Оба варианта отделяются запятой. В вашем, вопрошающий, варианте *"конечно"* - вводное слово, следовательно, запятая нужна, вот так: *"Конечно, нет!"*