# "Естественно"

Tags: пунктуация

Что-то меня заклинило: "Естественно(,) я в порядке" — тут ведь нужна запятая, да?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово *естественно* в данном предложении синонимично слову *конечно*. Запятую при *конечно* мы обсуждали [здесь.](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)