# «Хотите, сделаю». Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Хотите, я сделаю чаю?
Хотите, Вася сегодня вас проведает?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, нужна: эта запятая разделяет две основы.

Comment: "Конечно, нужна..." — Вы уверены, что здесь тоже нужна?

Comment: Продублирую здесь вопросы к Вам из соседней темы от другого участника. Вы считаете, что это сложное бессоюзное предложение? *Хотите* не может быть вводным?

Comment: Вот уж вводным не может быть никогда. А в "Конечно, нужна" – тоже нужна. Разумеется, нужна. Вероятно, нужна. Видимо, нужна. Разве "конечно" выпадает из этого ряда?

Comment: Здесь Вы в своём праве, наверное. Но да, выпадает. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [это обсуждение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/Запятая-после-Конечно).

Comment: Я внёс в ответ виртуальную правку, чтобы убрать свой минус.

Comment: @Niemand Вы не могли бы определить вид предложения с двумя основами, так как это вызывает у меня затруднение. Здесь нет союза, стоит запятая, но дело в том, что запятая в БСП ставится или при однородном перечислении, или при распространении. Здесь же более сложные отношения между частями сложного предложения, возможно изъяснительные (Аналог: Вы хотите, чтобы я приготовила Вам чаю). Поэтому я хотела спросить: почему первое предложение нельзя считать вводным? Ведь вводные предложения имеют более широкую тематику, чем вводные слова.

Answer (score 0):

Приведенный вами пример является бессоюзным сложным предложением, между частями которого устанавливаются условные отношения. Здесь знак тире является более нормативным.