# Нужна ли запятая перед "начальник"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Однако вести себя как добропорядочный гражданин начальник не собирался.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Однако вести себя как добропорядочный гражданин // он не собирался.***

1) Предложение разделено **на две части** по принципу тема — рема, предмет — сообщение о предмете. Между частями предложения делается **пауза**, обозначающая перелом интонации.

2) Так как предложение **инверсированное**, эта пауза обозначена в большей степени, чем в обычном простом предложении, **однако грамматических показателей для постановки запятой нет.**

3) При прямом порядке слов: *Однако он не собирался вести себя //как добропорядочный гражданин.*

Обратим внимание на то, что в этом случае пауза менее заметная.

Comment: Я немного изменил вопрос, но суть от того не меняется?

Comment: Разницы в постановке знаков препинания нет, но  разница в понимании текста может быть. Сочетание "гражданин начальник" нежелательно, определенная стилистическая некорректность в этом есть. Тогда надо редактировать предложение.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, конечно. Какая могла бы быть причина для постановки этой запятой? Легкая пауза в речи? - это не причина.

Comment: А из-за такого сочетания: гражданин начальник (гражданин-начальник)?

Comment: *Нет конечно* произносится убеждённым тоном, поэтому запятая не нужна: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: А вот менять вопрос уже после того как на него даны ответы - не есть хорошо, гражданин товарищ.

Comment: Слегка подкорректировал, тем более на тот момент ответ был только ваш.