# Надо ли выделять «конечно» запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, частицы

Надо ли выделять слово "конечно" запятыми?

> Вход(,) конечно(,) бесплатный.

Comment: Дайте контекст.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be

Answer (score 2):

**ПРАВИЛО**

Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно различать частицу ‟конечно”, которая не обособляется, и вводное ‟конечно”, которое обособляется. Разница между ними в следующем: ‟конечно”, как вводное, относится к чему-то, что известно или очевидно для слушающего речь; ‟конечно”, как частица, используется говорящим для категорического пресечения сомнения у воспринимающего речь. Взгляните на примеры:

> — Зачем тебе боксировать с ним, он же профессионал?
> — Конечно, мне не победить профессионального боксера, но я просто хочу поучаствовать. (Говорящий понимает, что слушателю известно или очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”.)
>
> — Как думаешь, у тебя есть шансы?
> — Конечно мне не победить профессионального боксера, идиот, я просто хочу поучаствовать. ( Говорящий понимает, что слушателю не известно и не очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”, а это слово используется для категорического пресечения сомнений у воспринимающего речь.)

> — Вы предлагаете при таком диагнозе заниматься спортом?
> — Конечно, профессиональным спортсменом ваш сын не станет, но тренировки пойдут ему на пользу. (Говорящий понимает, что слушателю известно или очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”.)
>
> — Ты думаешь, что он не станет профессиональным спортсменом?
> — Конечно он не станет профессиональным спортсменом: у него средние результаты даже на региональном уровне. ( Говорящий понимает, что слушателю не известно и не очевидно то, к чему относится ‟конечно”, а это слово используется для категорического пресечения сомнений у воспринимающего речь.)

Также я обнаружил, что вводное ‟конечно” можно заменить вводными ‟как вы знаете” или ‟как можно догадаться”, а частицу ‟конечно” нельзя заменить этими вводными. Взгляните на те же примеры:

> —Зачем тебе боксировать с ним, он же профессионал?
> — Конечно [можно заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”], мне не победить профессионального боксера, но я просто хочу поучаствовать.
>
> — Как думаешь, у тебя есть шансы?
> — Конечно [нельзя заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”] мне не победить профессионального боксера, идиот, я просто хочу поучаствовать.

> — Вы предлагаете при таком диагнозе заниматься спортом?
> — Конечно [можно заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”], профессиональным спортсменом ваш сын не станет, но тренировки пойдут ему на пользу.
>
> — Ты думаешь, что он не станет профессиональным спортсменом?
> — Конечно [нельзя заменить вводным ‟как вы знаете”] он не станет профессиональным спортсменом: у него средние результаты даже на региональном уровне.

**ОТВЕТ**

Контекст неизвестен, поэтому я просто предположу его. Предположим, что это написано на объявлении, в котором призывается прийти и послушать лекцию о проблеме рака груди. Ожидается, что никто и бесплатно не придёт, поэтому бесплатность прохода очевидна. В данном случае ‟конечно” будет вводным и пунктуация будет следующей: ‟Вход, конечно, бесплатный”.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

Пунктуация при слове ‟конечно” обычно является хаотичной, так как она не описана качественно в различных пособиях.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146596/discussion-on-answer-by-rumpelstiltskin------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Ответов по теме много, но вот **контекст** вроде бы никто не подбирал.

**СИТУАЦИЯ  (1):**  Рассказ о предстоящем мероприятии (фраза как  общая информация, обычно в конце рассказа)

*Вход, **конечно,**  бесплАтный.*

Синонимы: ***несомненно, разумеется***. Обособление **вводного слова** запятыми.

**СИТУАЦИЯ  (2):**  Идет обсуждение мероприятия (ответы на вопросы)

*— Вход бесплАтный?*

*— Вход **конЕчно** бесплатный, но при желании вы можете передать фонду какие-нибудь средства.*

**Частица**. Употр. для подтверждения сказанного: да, разумеется. Не обособляется.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_363&layout=item)

[Словари](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE&all=x)

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/Запятая-после-Конечно](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/5772/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE)